# Given x!=x in JavaScript. What is the type of 'x'?

Tags: javascript

I've been asked in a JavaScript interview

> If `x!=x` is `TRUE`, what is the possible type of `x`?

The interviewer told me there is only one possible type for `x` that gets this result.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {get: function () {return Math.random();}})`

Comment: Next interview question: Perform a code review on the following https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @Cerbrus as the question mentions _types_ lets fill in a couple more, _String_, `Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {get: function () {return String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 0xFFFF | 0);}})`, _Bool_, `Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {get: function () {return !(Math.random() * 2 | 0);}})`, _Function_ `Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {get: function () {return function () {};}})`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If `x!=x` is `true`, what is the possible type of `x`?

Assuming that `x` is meant to be a variable, the answer to this question is:

```
"number"
```

The only *value* that satisfies this requirement is `NaN`, which never equals itself.

As you can see, the *type* of `NaN` is `"number"`:
`typeof NaN === "number"`.

---

If `x` is merely a placeholder for *anything*, functions and object or array literals would work, too:

```
(function(){}) != (function(){})
({}) != ({})
[] != []
```

---

If `x` can be a getter, then there's all sorts of crazy options:

```
// Type == "string"
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
    get: function() { return String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 0xFFFF | 0); }
});

// Type == "boolean"
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
    get: function() { return !(Math.random() * 2 | 0); }
});

// Type == "function"
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
    get: function() { return function() {}; }
});

// Type == "object"
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
    get: function() { return ({}); }
});

// Type == "object"
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
    get: function() { return []; }
});
```

Using `with`:

```js
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, 'x', {
  get: function() { return []; } // any of the above types
});

with(o){
  alert(x != x);
}
```

(Thanks to [@Paul S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s))

Comment: Feel free to include code from my comments in this answer. You could also mention the `with` statement

Comment: The `with` statement?

Comment: If you have `var o = {}`, then `defineProperty` _x_ on `o`, then `with (o) {x != x;}`, you no longer need the global object

Comment: @PaulS.: Nifty! added :D

Answer (score 14):

The value is `NaN`, which is of type Number.

From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) for comparing equality:

> If x is NaN, return false.

`NaN` is never equal to anything, including itself.